# Can Rake run each test in a separate Ruby instance?

Tags: ruby, rake, rake-test

I have a very simple `Rakefile` to test a small Ruby gem. It looks like this:

```
Rake::TestTask.new
task :default => :test
```

It invokes two tests that define constants with the same name. This results in errors being output by the second test like this:

```
warning: already initialized constant xxxxx
```

The reason for this is because Rake executes all of the tests within a single Ruby instance:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -I"lib" -I"/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib" "/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/test*.rb"
```

**How should I specify that each test should be run in a separate Ruby instance ?**

I have achieved this as shown below but I wonder if there is a better way because this solution doesn't scale well for lots of tests.

```
Rake::TestTask.new(:one) { |t| t.test_files = %w(test/test_one.rb) }
Rake::TestTask.new(:two) { |t| t.test_files = %w(test/test_two.rb) }
task :default => [:one, :two]
```

Comment: Maybe it's easier to change the tests so they can run with the default setup. Move the constant definition into a helper file or define it under your test's namespace.

Comment: The easiest thing for me is to go with the above as I only have two tests. I hoped the question would reveal a better way of doing it, though, just in case I'd missed something trivial. It's a one-off scenario where there are two versions of the same stand-alone script and it isn't worth refactoring just to fix this specific issue. The tests are in a gem called `afsplitter` that I've put on rubygems if you're interested in the context.

Comment: You should use a test suite like [minitest](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Rake::TestTask`, you could define a test task in your `Rakefile` that loops through each test file and runs them with `sh` like this:

```
task :test do
  libs = ['lib', 
          '/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib', 
          '/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb']
  test_files = FileList['test/**/test*.rb']

  test_files.each do |test_file|
    includes = libs.map { |l| "-I#{l}"}.join ' '
    sh "ruby #{includes} #{test_file}"
  end
end
```